# Is there any way get buffering time form android youtube player api

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am using an android youtube api to create my own player, and I can't find an api to show curet buffering stats. Is any one know how to get the current buffering status?

The below code can get *whole video time* and *current play time*, but I need ***buffering time***

```
private String getTimesText() {
    int currentTimeMillis = player.getCurrentTimeMillis();
    int durationMillis = player.getDurationMillis();
    return String.format("(%s/%s)", formatTime(currentTimeMillis), formatTime(durationMillis));
}
```

I also saw there has a call back function on *PlaybackEventListener* but the same I can't find a way to get ***buffering time***

```
@Override
public void onBuffering(boolean isBuffering) {
    bufferingState = isBuffering ? "(BUFFERING)" : "";
    updateText();
    log("\t\t" + (isBuffering ? "BUFFERING " : "NOT BUFFERING ") + getTimesText());
}
```

Thanks for your time to read/answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no straight way to get total buffered time for YoutubePlayer so you can do instead and that should work,

```
long startBufferdTime = 0;
long endBufferdTime = 0;
long totalBufferringTime = 0;
@Override
public void onBuffering(boolean isBuffering) {


    if (isBuffering) {
        startBufferdTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    if (!isBuffering) {
        endBufferdTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    totalBufferringTime = endBufferdTime - startBufferdTime;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

generally when buffering starts the flag isBuffering will be true and when buffering ends it will be false.
So u need to calculate the time difference between these two flags.